# Swift use 'is' for function type, compiler behavior is different with runtime

Tags: swift, function, runtime, compiler-warnings

I am testing about `function is first class citizen` in Swift. and I got in trouble. Check the code below:

```
let f: Int -> Int = { $0 }
if f is (Int -> Int?) {  // compiler warning: 'is' test is always true
    print("hello")
} else {
    print("ops")  // runtime: this line is executed
}
```

I got a compiler warning in the `if` line says: "'is' test is always true". But when I run the code, console print "ops" which means `is` test is false. This confuses me. Why compiler says true when runtime says false?

Comment: A similar case previously flagged in this relevant thread: [Assigning tuples of associated types, why only allowed via explicit member-by-member assignment? (Error: cannot express tuple conversion)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157142/assigning-tuples-of-associated-types-why-only-allowed-via-explicit-member-by-me). This seems to be an issue with the `is` keyword and e.g. tuples and closures (here: closely related closure types): the compiler prompts that the `is` will fall through, whereas in fact, it does not at runtime. Possibly file a radar (I didn't for this issue in my thread).

Comment: Which version of swift are you using?

Comment: @sts2055 Swift 2.1.1 on Xcode 7.2

Comment: Ok, I thought it might be related to the regression in swift 2.2 but it is not. Swift 2.2 has problems inferring the type of optionals. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1024